# Does a/b mod m = (a mod m)/(b mod m)?

Tags: modulus, binomial-coefficients

Does `a/b mod m = (a mod m)/(b mod m)`?

I am trying to find nCr mod m for very large numbers. If `a/b mod m = (a mod m)/(b mod m)` then  think I will have solved my problem.

It is for Project Euler. I am using the nCr formula using factorials.

Comment: If b = m, then you'll have a divide by zero.

Comment: I don't think so.  All you need is one counter-example to prove it wrong, so try a few different sets of numbers, like 19, 9, and 4.

Comment: Are `a` and `b` relatively prime with `m` ?

Comment: If this belongs anywhere, it is stackexchange maths

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

No.

If you have `a=8, b=2, m=2` then you have `a/b mod m = 8/2 mod 2 = 4 mod 2 = 0`
and `(a mod m)/(b mod m) = (8 mod 2)/(2 mod 2) = 0/0 = NaN`
`NaN` is not equal to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

This identity does not hold. Here is a counter-example:

```
Let a = 21, b = 7, m = 7.
Then (21/7) = 3 and 3 mod 7 = 3
Alternately, 21 mod 7 = 0 and 7 mod 7 = 0.
But 0 / 0 is undefined (and certainly not 3).
```

Thus your identity does not hold. However, I am almost certain that it will hold if m and b are relatively prime.

Comment: Indeed. If `b` and `m` are relatively prime, there is a `c` such that `b*c mod m = 1`. Then `(a/b) mod m == (a/b)*(c*b) mod m == (a*c) mod m == (a mod m) * c mod m` and similarly for `b mod m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following link to evaluate (a/b)mod m.....
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html

The answer for evaluating is given at the end..

Comment: This is helpful but this should be a comment as it does not directly answer his question.